# Use column values as columns in sqlite3

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'd like to do the following on sqlite:

Convert this:

```
col1        col2
----------------
col1val1    col2val1
col1val2    col2val2
...         ...
```

To this:

```
col1       col2val1    col2val2   ...
-------------------------------------
col1val1   
col1val2
...
```

Is this possible without doing everything manually?

At the moment I have something like this:

```
select a.col1, 
   (select b.col1val1 from b1 b where condition), 
   (select b.col1val2 from b1 b where condition)
from a1 a
```

Problem is b1.col2 is dynamic and subject to change very often and also grow or shrink.

Is there any way to take this data and transpose the `col2val%` values as columns?
I could then use this value to get the intersection between col1 and col2.

Any help is greatly appreciated. I can provide more info if needed.

Comment: What would the data inside your actual output table be in this case?

Comment: SQLite does not support any pivot functionality, so the column names must be hardcoded.

Comment: You can do this with the [eval](https://sqlite.org/src/file/ext/misc/eval.c) extension to SQLite, though it's non-standard.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen suppose col1 has computer names and col2 has software names. The intesection would have the installed software version for that computer.

Comment: @forpas thanks, I also thought that was the case. shame tho.

Comment: @AnonCoward thanks for the tip, I'll take a look at it.